# How to split a string and send to another field

Tags: java, android

In my application I have three Edit text for username(Name,FirstName,LastName). If user enter the name (John Basker) in name field means automatically John send to firstname and Basker send to lastname.

I want this process happen to when the name field filled up. How to do it?

My code:

```
 arrowDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String personal_name = name.getText().toString();
                String [] array=personal_name.split("\\s+");
                firstname.setText(String.valueOf(array[0]));
                lastname.setText(String.valueOf(array[1]));
    }
});
```

Logcat:

I got an error in this line: `firstname.setText(String.valueOf(array[0]));`

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Answer (score 1):

```
                 //get value from editText
  String str=editText.getText().toString();
                //str = "firstname lastname";
  String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");    
                //split by  space
  splited[0] is firstname
  splited[1] is lastname

               //then it set to other  editText
 if(splited[0]) != null && !splited[0]).isEmpty())
{
 editText1.setText(String.valueOf(splited[0]));
 }
if(splited[1]) != null && !splited[1]).isEmpty())
{
 editText2.setText(String.valueOf(splited[1]));
}
```

Comment: First this question shouldn't be answered.... next your answer doesn't satisfy the question...

Comment: He want get split name ..my code receive value from edittext and split..whats wrong?

Comment: Along with split he want it to send the split ones to remaining text fields.. that code is missing

Comment: I got this error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Comment: if you type single name its occur

Comment: Thank you.. I got it .. But if i entered single string means firstname field only filled last name should be empty.. how to check that

Answer (score 0):

use the below code to detect white spaces

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
boolean found = matcher.find();
```

also use the SUBSTRING function to split the strings into two strings a and b
for eg: JOHN PATRIK then substring(0,3)